# How to update a table based on case condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, case

I have 4 tables.

- `PRIMARY` (`CASE_ID, ADDRESS, COUNTRY`)
- `SECONDARY` (`CASE_ID, ADDRESS, COUNTRY`)
- `DEST` (`CASE_ID, PRIMARY_ADDRESS, SECONDARY_ADDRESS, PRIMARY_COUNTRY, SECONDARY_COUNTRY`)
- `COUNTRIES` (`COUNTRY, RISK_SCORE`)

Update query:

```
update d
set d.PRIMARY_ADDRESS= ...?
    ,d.PRIMARY_COUNTRY= ...?
    ,d.SECONDARY_ADDRESS= ...?
    ,d.SECONDARY_COUNTRY= ...?
from DEST d
join PRIMARY p
on p.CASE_ID=d.CASE_ID
join SECONDARY s
on s.CASE_ID=d.CASE_ID
join COUNTRIES c
... ???
```

I have to update address and country columns of the `DEST` table with corresponding columns of `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY` table based on the addresses which have highest `risk_score` in `COUNTRIES` table. `Risk_Score` has values from 0 to 100.

`CASE_ID` and `COUNTRY` columns can be used as join columns. Please help.

Comment: try building a select with what you want. replace `update d set` with `select`. Then, when your query returns what you want. change the query back. You can use almost all of the same keywords in an update as you can in a select. In this case, I think you are looking for `case`

Comment: You need to join to COUNTRIES twice, once for the primary country and once for the secondary country, returning the country with the highest risk_score for each.

Answer (score 0):

This would be your basic select statement to get at the data. You could use it as an inner query and join to your destination table and do the update -

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT 
  P.CASE_ID, P.ADDRESS PRIM_ADDRESS, P.COUNTRY PRIM_COUNTRY, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE_ID ORDER BY RISK_SCORE DESC) AS RN_PRIMARY
  FROM [PRIMARY] P JOIN COUNTRIES C
  ON P.COUNTRY = C.COUNTRY)PRIMARYVALUES
JOIN 
(SELECT P.CASE_ID, P.ADDRESS SEC_ADDRESS, P.COUNTRY SEC_COUNTRY, 
  ROW_NUMBER()    OVER (PARTITION BY CASE_ID ORDER BY RISK_SCORE DESC) AS RN_SECONDARY
  FROM [SECONDARY] P JOIN COUNTRIES C
  ON P.COUNTRY = C.COUNTRY)SECONDARYVALUES 
 ON PRIMARYVALUES.CASE_ID = SECONDARYVALUES.CASE_ID
WHERE RN_PRIMARY = 1 AND RN_SECONDARY = 1
```

Here is the SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49642b/2